# Trying to sum two contingency tables - Error in table: non-conformable arrays

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, tidyverse

I'm trying to sum two frequency/contingency tables.

```
table(data$sample_idx1) + table(data$sample_idx2)
```

but I'm getting

> Error in table(data$sample_idx1) + table(data$sample_idx2) : 
>     non-conformable arrays

The problem (I think) is that "sample_idx1" and "sample_idx" don't have the exact same groups. For instance

sample_idx1

```
1   2   5 
10  12  12
```

sample_idx2

```
3 4 6
2 1 1
```

I would like to obtain something like:

```
1  2  3 4 5  6
10 12 2 1 12 1
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? I do not see how you add things in your concrete example. To me, this looks as if you are concatenating, but in a weired way.

Comment: You can use `cbind` if you want to concat column wise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposing you have two named vectors created by the `table` function, you can combine them with `c`:

```
table(sample_idx1)
#sample_idx1
# 1  2  5 
#10 12 12 

table(sample_idx2)
#sample_idx2
#3 4 6 
#2 1 1 

c(table(sample_idx1),table(sample_idx2))
# 1  2  5  3  4  6 
#10 12 12  2  1  1
```

If you need the resulting vector to be in order, you can use `order(names(x))`:

```
combine <- c(table(sample_idx1),table(sample_idx2))
combine[order(names(combine))]
# 1  2  3  4  5  6 
#10 12  2  1 12  1
```

Supposing the two tables have overlapping names, you can combine them with `tapply`:

```
combine <- c(table(sample_idx1),table(sample_idx3))
combine
# 1  2  5  2  3  6 
#10 12 12  1  2  1 

tapply(combine, names(combine), sum)
# 1  2  3  5  6 
#10 13  2 12  1
```

**Sample Data**

```
sample_idx1 <- rep(c(1,2,5),c(10,12,12))
sample_idx2 <- rep(c(3,4,6),c(2,1,1))
sample_idx3 <- rep(c(3,2,6),c(2,1,1))
```

Comment: If two tables overlap, e.g. `sample_idx1` has `3` in it, then `c()` cannot have an ideal output.

Answer (score 4):

An option is to write a function that tables the data from the original, given a vector of columns.

```
table2 <- function(x, cols){
  y <- unlist(x[cols])
  table(y)
}

table2(data, c("sample_idx1", "sample_idx2"))
```